# Which is a better data structure to use in this situation: Dictionary<string, Func<object>> or Dictionary<string, object>?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, dictionary

I'm using C# 4.0.  I am performing a bunch of computations on each row of a `System.Data.DataTable`.  I can't give out the actual code, but it boils down to something like this:

```
DataTable table = GetMyTableFromSomewhere();
string[] columnNames = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToArray();
foreach (var row in table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
{
    Dictionary<string, object> values = columnNames.ToDictionary(c => c, c => row[c]);
    EvaluateExpressionUsingTheseValues(values);
}
```

Then `EvaluateExpressionUsingTheseValues` would access `"SomeColumn"` via `values["SomeColumn"]`.

My thought is that creating a dictionary inside the loop is resource-intensive.  Therefore something like this may be more time efficient:

```
DataTable table = GetMyTableFromSomewhere();
int rowIndex = -1;
var values = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => new
{ 
    Key = c.ColumnName, 
    Value = new Func<object>(() => table.Rows[rowIndex][c.ColumnName])
}).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);

for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < table.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
{
    EvaluateExpressionUsingTheseValues(values);
}
```

And then `values["SomeColumn"]` in `EvaluateExpressionUsingTheseValues` would just be `values["SomeColumn"]()`, instead.

I see the first as having heavy per-iteration overhead to build a dictionary, but then fast lookup, whereas the second has no per-iteration overhead in terms of building a dictionary, but then slower lookup.

Which is better?

Comment: Have you considered timing it, to see which runs faster?

Comment: EvaluateExpressionUsingTheseValues must receive Dictionary<string,object>?

Comment: @LostHobbit I'm working on a tool that hasn't been released yet and we don't know heuristics of how large the tables will be row-wise, column-wise, and how complex the expressions inside `EvaluateExpressionUsingTheseValues` will be.

Comment: @LuizCarlosBrazão No, it doesn't need to be that, per se.  But it needs to be some sort of generic mapping structure.  I think a `DataRow` would be quickest in this usage of `EvaluateExpressionUsingTheseValues`, but the evaluating method needs to be more generic than relying on a DataTable/Set/Row because it's going to be used elsewhere, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find that the solution with `Dictionary<string, Func<object>>` has much more overhead.

The reason is that these `Func<object>` delegates live on closure objects that need to be allocated. The cost of that is probably much higher than simply indexing into your row once.

Furthermore, you'll probably have to do the indexing later anyway. The solution with `Func<object>` would then benefit from a cache inside `EvaluateExpressionUsingTheseValues(values)` to avoid multiple evaluations. But that is what the first solution really already is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that we can answer this for you. It depends on which is better for *your* situation.

Personally, though, I would take the first option, as it's much easier to decipher. A future developer's brain would probably explode upon seeing the second option, unless it was very well-documented!

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest creating a Name/Value class to reflect the DataRow, creating large numbers of AnonymouseType will decrease the performance even if their are the same.

U may do a benchmark with this:

```
public class DataTableHelper
{
    class RowItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
    public IEnumerable<RowItem> Convert(System.Data.DataTable table)
    {
        string[] columns = (from System.Data.DataColumn n in table.Columns select n.ColumnName).ToArray();

        foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (string column in columns)
                yield return new RowItem() { Name = column, Value = row[column] };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One important factor is what percentage of that data will you end up actually needing?  If you know that you're going to use every value in every column for each row (maybe you're printing it all out to the screen, or calculating aggregate data) then you may as well just compute the actual values right off the bad to populate your dictionary.  If you know you're only going to be sparsely accessing data, pulling a small percentage of the columns from just some of the rows, then maybe, possible, in certain situations, it would be worthwhile to use the second approach that defers evaluation.

Having said that, since populating the actual values isn't inherently all that complex, it's unlikely to be all that much of a win, so the simpler (first) approach is most likely a better option.  Of course, if you know you won't need certain rows/columns filtering them out as early as possible (ideally not even fetching them from the database) will be best.